# "/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy. Try again later" in Solaris 11

Tags: users, solaris, privileges

I've been playing around with a Solaris 11 system, where I've made several user-accounts for myself.  Anyway, I gave one of my unprivileged account the `solaris.*` auth, and then tried to give another unprivileged account the `System Administrator` profile:

```
user$ auths
solaris.*
user$ pfexec usermod -P"+System Administrator" user2
```

This failed with the following error-message (yes, repeated three times):

```
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
```

I've "tried again later" - even after just rebooting - and each time I've get the same result.  This is a completely different error than when a user without the `solaris.*` (or one of the `assign`-auths) tries the command.

I've also tried to explicitly add auths regarding assigning profiles, auths and roles - eg. `solaris.profile.assign` - in addition to `solaris.*` (like how `solaris.grant` had to be explicitly assigned); but that didn't help (nor show up when I did a `auths` - only `solaris.*` showed).

I have however successfully used `usermod` to assign these things while *root* or while using a user with the *Primary Administrator* profile (I copy-pasted in from a previous Solaris-version).

However I really thought `solaris.*` - or for that matter just the `solaris.profile.assign` - ought to have been enough to use `usermod` to give privileges to other users...

So what does the (triple) error-message mean?  Why doesn't it work?  And if it *shouldn't* work, why not?  And what would be the correct "least" combination of auths and/or profiles to make it work?

Comment: The output shown suggests the passwd file is in a read only state, within the context of your pfexec run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why doesn't it work?

The error messages

```
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
/usr/lib/passmgmt: Password file(s) busy.  Try again later
```

likely mean you don't have permission to create a file in `/etc`.

The only source of that error message that I can find is in the `passmgmt` [source code](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/cmd/passmgmt/passmgmt.c#1597) and is generated when `passmgmt` fails either to create the file `/etc/.pwd.lock` or can not actually lock the file if it already exists.

`passmgmt`, and likely many other Solaris utilities, attempt to lock the password files with an `/etc/.pwd.lock` file.  ([source code link for locking the password files](http://src.illumos.org/source/xref/illumos-gate/usr/src/lib/libc/port/gen/lckpwdf.c#LOCKFILE)).

Given that you can successfully use `usermod` while `root`, this doesn't look like a problem where an errant process holds a lock on `/etc/.pwd.lock`, so the only failure per the published Illumos source (admittedly a bit out-of-date now) that generates the error messages that you see is a failure to create `/etc/.pwd.lock`, almost certainly because your process doesn't have write permissions to `/etc`.

That's *why* it's failing.  Unfortunately, I don't have the time to research whether it *should* fail or not.

Comment: Seems reasonable....  Neither do I know if it should work or not - still having an auth so that a user can do something (eg. solaris.profile.assign), but it turns out he can't anyway because he doesn't have the permission to make a lock, does seem a bit redundant...  I guess the difference when doing it through profiles, is that profiles doesn't just assigns auths and other profiles; but also assigns the ability run specific commands as system-users (sometimes including root) through /etc/security/exec_attr .